# OneSignal-Pushnotification small icon not displayed on Android

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, android-drawable, onesignal

We have a Cordova-App which contains a file 'icon.png' in every drawable-xy folder. We provide push notifications using OneSignal. The notifications are working as expected. Except the small icon. There is only a blank icon on the top bar of my phone, where app-symbols are displayed. I tried using the following snippet:

```
{
   ...
   "small_icon" : "@android:drawable/icon.png"
   ....
}
```

I also tried lots and lots of other variations without "android", without "drawable", without slash, with .png and without .png. etc. etc.

I found this in the documentation: (https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification)

```
small_icon: stringOptional
Specific Android icon to use. If blank the app icon is used. Must be the drawable resource name.
```

Android tells about drawable resources: (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

With an image saved at res/drawable/myimage.png, this layout XML applies the image to a View:

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/myimage" />
```

which should be `@drawable/icon` for me then. (does not work)

Changing the large icon to an url works for me, large icon with a drawable does not, aswell.

What is the correct usage of this property `small_icon`?

Comment: Is your device pre lollipop or not?

Comment: It is not pre-lollipop. I tested on 5.0.2, 5.1.1, 6.0, Hardware- and Emulator-Devices.

Comment: The small notification icon is used in all versions of Android. Starting with Lollipop 5.0 the small icon will be forced to only use the alpha channel and all opaque parts will become white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Android SDK API 21,your small icon must be like this

[image]

white and transparent only.

So, you can code this.

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_aphla_logo);
    } else {
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo);
    }
```

Comment: This is Android-Java-Code. My Application consists of pure JavaScript. The tip with transparent icons is good, though. I will try again with a semi-transparent png.

Comment: Ok, I do not think this answer is great at all, but the solution is: the icon has to be white-transparent only.

Comment: Is there any way to create colored small icon image instead of white ?

Answer (score 3):

The small icon is a Android resource which is a name without a file extension or path. In your case you need to set `"small_icon" : "icon"` in the JSON payload sent to the OneSignal [create notification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification) REST API call.

For Cordova you need to place your icon files in `<project-root>/platforms/android/res`. There should be one for each resolution and using the [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html) the recommend way to create this small icon. If you set the name to `ic_stat_onesignal_default` it will be used by the OneSignal SDK for all OneSignal notifications unless you override it in the JSON message. The full path for one of the icon files should be `<project-root>/platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi-v11/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png` for example.

See OneSignal's [Customize Notification Icons](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons) guide for full details.